# Using Webpack to bundle files for use in another project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

I made a small app with create-react-app and I want it to be rendered inside a modal on a php site.

I have copied src folder to another directory, installed Webpack and Babel, defined a .babelrc and webpack.config.js files, yet when I run `webpack --mode development` it produces a file which HTML cannot use -

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Component' of undefined
at eval (App.js:451)
at Module../src/app/App.js (bundle.js:429)
at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:20)
at eval (index.js:6)
at Module../src/index.js (bundle.js:591)
at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:20)
at bundle.js:84
at bundle.js:87
```

Added React from CDN, how should `webpack.config.js` be configured to produce what I need?

In act of desperation I have bundled React app to one file by hand and then pasted it into Babel REPL, played around with options and I finally got a file that can be interpreted by 'normal' static sites

How to reproduce it with Webpack, so I can have an automatic pipeline?

Comment: are you sure there is a `<div id='root' ></div>` element

Comment: yes, I am sure. Isn't something missing from files?
[Codepen](https://codepen.io/westedcrean/project/editor/ZWwYoe)

Comment: @WestedCrean For some reason, the React app appears as `<app user_id="1234"></app>` inside of the root element. What does the render function look like for `<App />`?

Comment: Check here: [PasteBin](https://pastebin.com/vXvZN6G8) it's a totally normal code and was working fine with create-react-app. I have bundled it using Webpack and Babel transpiler but it's still not working.